# I setup a second router as a bridge, what is the best practice for handling multiple SSID's on the same network?

Tags: wireless-networking, bridge, wireless-bridge

I have a router in the basement that produces a wireless signal named "HomeNetwork" at 2.4ghz. I ran an Ethernet cable upstairs and setup an old Linksys E4200 in bridge mode. The bridge functionality is working, but I'm wondering how I should handle the additional WiFi names.

1. Is it better to have 3 different WiFi names? ("HomeNetwork", "Upstairs2", "Upstairs5" )
2. Should I name all 3 SSID's the same thing? Are there any downsides/benefits to this?

If they are all named the same thing, should they all run on the same channel?

Comment: Use one ssid on the main dhcp server router, and switch all "slave" routers to bridged mode with the same ssid. Channel is independent from ssid.

Comment: Okay, I know channels are independent from the SSID. But Would it make sense to use the same channel? Or use different channels?

Comment: @BigElittles just spread the 3 routers SSID across the spectre for example in clear avoid having them on the same channel or to close otherwise you could experience poor network speed.

Comment: @BigElittles different channels are best in your scenario.  Certain extenders want to be on the same channel which might be your source of confusion.  I'd use software like [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.com/products/inssider/) to pick the best channels for each.  If you set channels rather than selecting "auto" remember that it may need adjustment from time to time (I.e. Your neighbors channel might change, and now yours does)

Answer (score 0):

Different names. Same SSID. Different channels. I've been running this setup at home for years (Router is Unit0, routers running as access points only are Unit1 & Unit2, all using SSID "NetworkName", on channels 1, 6, 11). Handoff between access points is seamless - devices automatically connect to whichever is closest.